# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'facebook'

Tags: django

Im trying to implement `django-socialregistration`, with all dependences included, I just followed [those instruction](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration)s. im having this error after authenticating with facebook:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'facebook'
C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\socialregistration\views.py in facebook_login
    108. if not request.facebook.check_session(request):
```

what im missing? some middleware excepted? thx :)

Comment: where does the doc says that request object has a facebook attribute, BTW what you mean by "request.facebook.check_session(request)".

Comment: I mean that python crash at this line.

Comment: Please review your selected answer. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

adding `'facebook.djangofb.FacebookMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`  will attach a `facebook` object to every incoming request.

Comment: Not solved. I have this same problem, and this is already in my middleware. Additionally, as noted by Spajus, you are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you need 
`'socialregistration.middleware.FacebookMiddleware'`
 in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

not `'facebook.djangofb..'` one.